# How do I disable/enable authentication at runtime in Asp.Net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

A website is per default anonymous access only.

The admin has a button to switch the site into maintenance mode, which should enable authorization using the built-in CookieAuthentication (flip a bit in a database, not relevant for this post).

In order to make that work, I first configured cookie authentication (in startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login");
                });
} 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Then on relevant controllers, I put an `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  //removed
}
```

This works perfectly - cookie auth kicks in when authorize-attribute is present. So far so good.

Now I want to **disable** authorization **at runtime** when maintenance mode is off.

### Attempted Solution

This is what I ended up with after a lot of trial and error and research.

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        IMaintenanceModeDataService ds = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMaintenanceModeDataService>();

        if (!ds.IsMaintenanceModeEnabled)
        {
            //Maintenance mode is off, no need for authorization
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal user = context.HttpContext.User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //when the user is authenticated, we don't need to do anything else.
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //we're in maintenance mode AND the user is not 
                //It is outside the scope of this to redirect to a login
                //We just want to display maintenancemode.html
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("/maintenancemode.html");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

[MaintenanceModeAwareAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  //removed
}
```

This works great when the site is in maintenance mode.

When the site is NOT in maintenance mode, the cookie authentication still kicks in and requires auth. I could remove that and try to implement my own auth, but that would be stupid, when we already have perfectly well-crafted solutions built-in.

### How do I disable authorization when the site is NOT in maintenance mode (**at runtime**)?

### Notes:

Q: Why not handle this by doing x (which requires serverside access to config, environment vars, server or similar)?

A: Because this needs to be immediately accessible to non-technical admin-users by clicking a button in the backend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes you can!

The authorization system in ASP.NET Core is extensible and you can implement your scenario easily with [poliy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Two main things to know to get going:

- an authorization policy is made of one or more [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#requirements-1)
- all of the requirements must be satisfied for a policy to succeed

Our goal is then to create a requirement which is satisfied if any of the following statements is true:

- the maintenance mode is not enabled, or
- the user is authenticated

#### Let's see the code!

The first step is to create our requirement:

```
public class MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

We then have to implement the handler for this requirement, which will determine if it's satisfied or not. The good news is handlers support dependency injection:

```
public class MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement>
{
    private readonly IMaintenanceModeDataService _maintenanceModeService;

    public MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirementHandler(IMaintenanceModeDataService maintenanceModeService)
    {
        _maintenanceModeService = maintenanceModeService;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!_maintenanceModeService.IsMaintenanceModeEnabled || context.User.Identities.Any(x => x.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Next, we need to create an authorization policy that uses this requirement, and you have 2 choices here:

- you can redefine the default policy, used when "empty" `[Authorize]` attributes are used, or
- create an explicit policy that you'll have to reference in your attributes, like `[Authorize(Policy = "<your-policy-name>")]`

There's no right or wrong answer; I'd pick the first option is my application had only one authorization policy, and the second one if it had several of them. We'll see how to do both:

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // 1. This is how you redefine the default policy
        // By default, it requires the user to be authenticated
        //
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/30eec7d2ae99ad86cfd9fca8759bac0214de7b12/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationOptions.cs#L22-L28
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement())
            .Build();

        // 2. Define a specific, named policy that you can reference from your [Authorize] attributes
        options.AddPolicy("MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUser", builder => builder
            .AddRequirements(new MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirement()));
    });
```

Next, you need to register the requirement handler as an `IAuthorizationHandler`, as indicated in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#handler-registration-1)

```
// The lifetime you pick is up to you
// You just need to remember that it's got a dependency on IMaintenanceModeDataService, so if you
// registered the implementation of IMaintenanceModeDataService as a scoped service, you shouldn't
// register the handler as a singleton
// See this captive dependency article from Mark Seeman: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUserRequirementHandler>();
```

The final step is to apply the `[Authorize]` attributes on your controllers/actions as needed.

```
// 1. If you redefined the default policy
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

// 2. If you defined an explicit policy
[Authorize(Policy = "MaintenanceModeDisabledOrAuthenticatedUser")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: An unrelated comment, but one I feel is important, is that ASP.NET Core 2.2 is not supported anymore by Microsoft as of the 23rd of December 2019; see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle. I'd recommend targetting ASP.NET Core 2.1 which is a long-term support (LTS) release, or thinking about upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Great in-depth answer! Thanks!

Comment: Very useful answer! For my case I wanted to totally disable authentication for some API testing. Based my solution on this but simplified the handler to just handle the requirement successfully `context.Succeed(requirement); return Task.CompletedTask;`

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that could not be done .The accept of authorization is different from authentication, when `context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false`, it will always redirect to login page.

It's better to have actions that must or may require authorization in a controller together, and unauthorized actions in a separate controller with `[AllowAnonymous]`.

```
if (!user.IsMaintenanceModeEnabled)
{
    context.Result = new RedirectResult("Another controller with [AllowAnonymous]");
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since current pages need work perfectly with `anonymous` mode, then authentication should NOT be in `Controller` level.

I think your requests are:

1. If a `Maintancer` login system,

   - run extra code to show `maintance elements`(switch button or others) on page, so `Maintancer` can switch page with different mode, and do `maintancer actions`
2. If user visit site `anonymously`, `anonymous-mode elements` will render to browser
3. If user login but not an `Maintancer`, `normal-user-mode elements` will render to browser

To resolve those, The key is to block unauthorized user to visit `Maintancer ACTIONS`, instead of `controller`.

my suggestions are:

1. in _Layout.cshtml page, check if `Maintancer Login`, then enject `switch button`
2. in the actions or pages that could visit anornymously, check if "Maintancer Login" && `IsMaintenanceMode`, then show `Maintancer-authorized elements`, like `Delete Post`, `Edit Content`, ...
3. in Controller.Actions that works only for `Maintancer`(like `Delete Post`), add `[Authorize(Roles="Maintancer")]` or `[Authorize(Policy="Maintancer")]` or you customized authorize.