# Using a condition within an authorization policy handler and reverting to the default behavior if it is not met

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to implement a feature in my WebAPI where, if a certain condition is met, the authorization automatically succeeds, and, if it fails, the default authorization system is used. I followed the first answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549828/how-do-i-disable-enable-authentication-at-runtime-in-asp-net-core-2-2) question, and have this code in the handler:

```
public class AuthDisableOrEnableHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthDisableOrEnableRequirement>
{

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthDisableOrEnableRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (<condition>)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            //revert to default Authorize behavior
        }
        

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So, for example, if the condition is true, the user can choose not to send a Token in the header of the HTTP request, while if it is not met, the user MUST send the token in order to use the method.

**Update 24/07/2023**

Thanks to Corey Sutton's answers and comments I managed to get it to work. Here's what I did.
What you have to do is follow what he did and then make the following changes:

1. Make `NoAuthHandler` extend from `AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>` instead of implementing the interface `IAuthenticationHandler`.
2. Override the `HandleAuthenticationAsync` method, create a ticket, and then return `AuthenticateResult.Success(authTicket)`.
3. Implement the `GetAuthenticationSchemeBasedOnCondition()` method in 'Program.cs' by returning the string "NoAuth" if a condition is met and `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` if it is not.

Here is the code for steps 1 and 2:

```
public class NoAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private HttpContext _context;

        public NoAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }
        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            string randomName = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(100000, 999999).ToString(); //this is only for testing, you should probably change it

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                                                new ClaimsIdentity(
                                                    Scheme.Name,
                                                    nameType: randomName,
                                                    roleType: "Test")
                                                );

            var authTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authTicket));
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for step 3:

```
string GetAuthenticationSchemeBasedOnCondition()
{
    var condition = true; 
    if(condition == true) //insert the condition you actually want here.
    {
        return "NoAuth";
    }
    return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that my answer may be on the "general" side because your question leaves a lot to interpret. I will answer your question based on the assumption that you're using JWT.

If you want to fall back to the default authentication behavior if a certain condition isn't met, then you shouldn't handle the authorization in your custom handler.

What you can do is remove the authorization from your handler if the condition is met and let the default middleware handle the case when the condition is not met.

If you haven't yet, you'll need to setup your application to use multiple Authentication Schemes. Add JwtBearer as the DefaultScheme and a custom "NoAuth" scheme as the DefaultSchemeForPolicy:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(/*...*/)
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, NoAuthHandler>("NoAuth", _ => { });
```

Your NoAuthHandler could look something like this here:

```
public class NoAuthHandler : IAuthenticationHandler
{
    private HttpContext _context;

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        _context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ForbidAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        _context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then, in your Authorization policy, you are able to then select the scheme based on conditions:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("DisableOrEnable", policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policyBuilder.AuthenticationSchemes = new[]
        {
            GetAuthenticationSchemeBasedOnCondition() // returns "NoAuth" or JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme based on the condition
        };
    });
});
```

Make sure you implement `GetAuthenticationSchemeBasedOnCondition` method according to your business logic. Examples would be something like reading a config value, database flag, environment variable, etc.

In the controller, you can apply the policy:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "DisableOrEnable")]
public IActionResult SecureEndpoint()
{
    // ...
}
```

If the condition is met and "NoAuth" is returned, the NoAuthHandler doesn't do any authentication and allows everyone access. If the JwtBearer scheme is returned, then the default Jwt authentication happens.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I implemented the NoAuthHandler, but when I try to add the scheme to the application I get this error:
`The type '<MyNoAuthHandler>' cannot be used as type parameter 'THandler' in the generic type or method 'AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme<TOptions, THandler>(string, Action<TOptions>?)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '<MyNoAuthHandler>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeOptions>'.`

Comment: Does your NoAuthHandler properly inherit from the base class? IAuthenticationHandler is an interface, but when you're using AddScheme<TOptions, THandler>, it expects THandler to be a type that extends AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>, not IAuthenticationHandler.

So, in order to correctly implement the NoAuthHandler, it should extend from AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>, not implement IAuthenticationHandler